# Unable to use multiple instances of MobileServiceClient concurrently

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I structured my project into multiple mobile services, grouped by the application type eg:

my-core.azure-mobile.net (user, device)
my-app-A.azure-mobile.net (sales, order, invoice)
my-app-B.azure-mobile.net (inventory & parts)
I'm using custom authentication for all my services, and I implemented my own SSO by setting the same master key to all 3 services.

Things went well when I tested using REST client, eg. user who "logged in" via custom api at my-core.azure-mobile.net is able to use the returned JWT token to access restricted API of the other mobile services.

However, in my xamarin project, only the first (note, in sequence of creation) MobileServiceClient object is working properly (eg. returning results from given table). The client object are created using their own url and key respectively, and stored in a dictionary.

If i created client object for app-A then only create for app-B, I will be able to perform CRUD+Sync on sales/order/invoice entity, while CRUD+Sync operation on inventory/part entity will just hang there. The situation is inverse if I swap the client object creation order.

I wonder if there is any internal static variables used within the MobileServiceClient which caused such behavior, or it is a valid bug ?

=== code snippet ===

```
public class AzureService
{
    IDictionary<String, MobileServiceClient> services = new Dictionary<String, MobileServiceClient>();

    public MobileServiceClient Init (String key, String applicationURL, String applicationKey)
    {
        return services[key] = new MobileServiceClient (applicationURL, applicationKey);
    }

    public MobileServiceClient Get(String key) 
    {
        return services [key];
    }

    public void InitSyncContext(MobileServiceSQLiteStore offlineStore)
    {
        // Uses the default conflict handler, which fails on conflict
        // To use a different conflict handler, pass a parameter to InitializeAsync. 
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=521416
        var syncHandler = new MobileServiceSyncHandler ();

        foreach(var client in services) {
            client.Value.SyncContext.InitializeAsync (offlineStore, syncHandler);
        }
    }

    public void SetAuthenticationToken(String uid, String token)
    {
        var user = new MobileServiceUser(uid);
        foreach(var client in services) {
            client.Value.CurrentUser = user;
            client.Value.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken = token;
        }
    }

    public void ClearAuthenticationToken() 
    {
        foreach(var client in services) {
            client.Value.CurrentUser = null;
        }
    }
}
```

=== more code ===

```
public class DatabaseService
{
    public static MobileServiceSQLiteStore LocalStore = null;
    public static string Path { get; set; }
    public static ISet<IEntityMappingProvider> Providers = new HashSet<IEntityMappingProvider> ();

    public static void Init (String dbPath)
    {
        LocalStore = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(dbPath);

        foreach(var provider in Providers) {
            var types = provider.GetSupportedTypes ();
            foreach(var t in types) {
                JObject item = null;

                // omitted detail to create JObject using reflection on given type

                LocalStore.DefineTable(tableName, item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

=== still code ===

```
public class AzureDataSyncService<T> : IAzureDataSyncService<T>
{
    public MobileServiceClient ServiceClient { get; set; }

    public virtual Task<List<T>> GetAll()
    {
        try
        {
            var theTable = ServiceClient.GetSyncTable<T>();
            return theTable.ToListAsync();
        }
        catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException msioe)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("GetAll<{0}> EXCEPTION TYPE: {1}, EXCEPTION:{2}", typeof(T).ToString(), msioe.GetType().ToString(), msioe.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("GetAll<{0}> EXCEPTION TYPE: {1}, EXCEPTION:{2}", typeof(T).ToString(), e.GetType().ToString(), e.ToString());
        }
        List<T> theCollection = Enumerable.Empty<T>().ToList();
        return Task.FromResult(theCollection);
    }
}
```

=== code ===

```
public class UserService : AzureDataSyncService<User>
{
}

public class PartService : AzureDataSyncService<Part>
{
}

const string coreApiURL = @"https://my-core.azure-mobile.net/";
const string coreApiKey = @"XXXXX";

const string invApiURL = @"https://my-inventory.azure-mobile.net/";
const string invApiKey = @"YYYYY";

public async void Foo ()
{
    DatabaseService.Providers.Add (new CoreDataMapper());
    DatabaseService.Providers.Add (new InvDataMapper ());
    DatabaseService.Init (DatabaseService.Path);

    var coreSvc = AzureService.Instance.Init ("Core", coreApiURL, coreApiKey);
    var invSvc = AzureService.Instance.Init ("Inv", invApiURL, invApiKey);
    AzureService.Instance.InitSyncContext (DatabaseService.LocalStore);
    AzureService.Instance.SetAuthenticationToken("AAA", "BBB");

    UserService.Instance.ServiceClient = coreSvc;
    PartService.Instance.ServiceClient = invSvc;

    var x = await UserService.GetAll(); // this will work
    var y = await PartService.GetAll(); // but not this
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok to use multiple MobileServiceClient objects, but not with the same local database. The offline sync feature uses a particular system tables to keep track of table operations and errors, and it is not supported to use the same local store across multiple sync contexts.

I'm not totally sure why it is hanging in your test, but it's possible that there is a lock on the local database file and the other sync context is waiting to get access.

You should instead use different local database files for each service and doing push and pull on each sync context. With your particular example, you just need to move **LocalStore** out of **DatabaseService** and into a dictionary in **AzureService**.

In general, it seems like an unusual design to use multiple services from the same client app. Is there a particular reason that the services need to be separated from each other?

Comment: sorry for late reply, this is an old question that I've already solved using similar approach you mentioned above. The reason behind multiple services within same client is because we developed multiple software suites that share the same login/billing system (eg. microsoft office).